# Highcharts, Safari 6 and the curious case of the vertically aligned bar chart

Tags: cordova, safari, webkit, highcharts

I've recently updated Safari 6 and what's happened is that Highcharts (2.3.0+; 2.2.3 doesn't render the series at all) now renders my dynamic bar charts vertically with other display issues (labels aren't positioned properly, hovering on certain elements is activated when the cursor is noticebly further away than the element).

[image: Bar chart rendering incorrectly with incorrect label positions on hover]

I've attempted stripping things back and it stills renders it with the errors. I did a basic JSFiddle of a chart and it seems to render perfectly.

I downgraded Safari 6 back to 5.1.7 (sheesh, that was a headache) and it renders normally. I'm just a little bit worried as I'm using it in a PhoneGap/Cordova app and if Webkit is shared with the iOS stuff then it potentially will break when Mobile Safari is updated to the latest version of Webkit. There's potential that because the chart is located within a complex view affected by significant dynamic CSS styles that perhaps Safari/Webkit is altering something in particular with how Highcharts calculates certain things. This is actually a super-hard thing to figure out and debug and I haven't found much online with others that have experienced the same, just hoping someone here might have experienced the same or have some valuable insight to offer.

Edit: I should also mention that other graph types (column, line) that I use are also rendering incorrectly, but none as incorrect as the bar type.

Comment: Here is a question for you because we ran into the same issue. Do you dynamically change the chart type?

Comment: Not at all. Only the series. The other stuff is that the page where the results gets shown is always wiped and redrawn when the results are being calculated. I wondered if perhaps it was something to do with getting the dimensions of the renderTo element, but even when I set those via CSS it still mucks up the rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After putting this off, I came back to the issue and found that I had some CSS settings which Highcharts/Safari doesn't seem to like.

To facilitate mobile development and rendering accuracy/smoothness within PhoneGap, I've got some broad ranging CSS definitions:

```
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout:  none;
    -moz-touch-callout:     none;
    touch-callout:          none;
    -webkit-user-drag:      none;
    -moz-user-drag:         none;
    user-drag:              none;
    -webkit-user-select:    none;
    -khtml-user-select:     none;
    -moz-user-select:       none;
    -ms-user-select:        none;
    user-select:            none;

    /* This stops the coloured overlay when a person clicks an element */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

    /* Stuff to do with positioning and utilising the 3D engine for rendering speed */
    -webkit-transform:      translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform:         translateZ(0);
    transform:              translateZ(0);
}
```

When I remove the transform declarations, Highcharts works fine. Probably not good to run such a broad selector on it as no doubt the 3D positioning probably mucks with the SVG stuff. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcDcW/) that shows the break (view with Safari 6 -- haven't tested in anything else as I've been developing for iOS).

Comment: Seems to be a Webkit thing as Chrome is affected as well. Firefox is fine (but there is a slight difference between the two charts -- watch the grid lines when you switch between the two).